# chrome MutationObserver for new paragraph text

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I haven't really understood quite yet how to use the mutationObserver but what I currently have seems somewhat right... I'd like to do an action every time new `p` tag appears within the code.. Here is my code thus far:

```
var target = $('p');
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get({ getInjection: true }, function(getInject) {
        var getInjectionState = getInject.getInjection;
        if(getInjectionState == true) {
                arrayOfP = $("p").text();
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(arrayOfP, manageResponse);
            }
        });
    });    
});
observer.observe(target[0], { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });
```

This code is within a content script in a chrome extension. Why isn't it working? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [`mutation-summary`](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary) library is worth a mention here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `observer.observe` should observe the parent/container element to which the new `p` elements are added or `document.body`.

   - `observer.observe($('.some-container-selector')[0], .....`
   - `observer.observe(document.body, .....`
2. inside the callback you should check whether the added node is actually `p`:

   ```
   mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
     Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) {
       if (node.nodeType != 1) return; // only process Node.ELEMENT_NODE
       if (node.localName != 'p') { // not P but might be DIV with P inside
         node = node.querySelector('p');
         if (!node) return;
       }
       // now we have our P node
       console.log("Got P!", node);
     });
   });
   ```

---

---

As an alternative here's a function I reuse for several years, with an uglier but much faster for-loop:

```
function setMutationHandler(baseNode, selector, cb) {
  new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for (var i=0, ml=mutations.length, m; (i<ml) && (m=mutations[i]); i++)
      for (var j=0, nodes=m.addedNodes, nl=nodes.length, n; (j<nl) && (n=nodes[j]); j++)
        if (n.nodeType == 1) 
          if ((n = n.matches(selector) ? [n] : n.querySelectorAll(selector)) && n.length)
            if (!cb.call(this, [].slice.call(n)))
              return;
  }).observe(baseNode, {subtree:true, childList:true}); 
}
```

Usage (here the callback would receive only `p` elements under `.some-container-class`):

```
setMutationHandler(document, '.some-container-class p', function(nodes) {
  nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    console.log("Got node", node);
    // do something
  });
  //this.disconnect(); // disconnect the observer, useful for one-time jobs
  //return true; // continue enumerating current batch of mutations
});
```

The last for-loop occurs quite rarely comparing to the setMutationHandler's loops so it may be replaced with a more concise `[].forEach.call(nodes, ...` or `Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, ....` or jQuery wrapper with `.each`.

P.P.S. for Chrome pre-34 this is required somewhere at the start of the script:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches)
    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quality post! I'm still pretty new to javascript, how would I implement thi into my code? Do I need both the 2nd bullet and the usage or am I missing something?

Comment: @Katie, do #1 and #2, ignore #3.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but I seem to be getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: mutation.addedNodes.forEach is not a function`.. Here is my implementation on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8h37ta1e/). Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: Ah, I've been using my custom handler for so long and forgot that `addedNodes` isn't an array, see the updated code.