# Selecting HTML tag once it has been added to the DOM?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get chatbox text, from facebook Chat, the text is encapsulated in the span tag

```
<span class="_5y15">Some Text</span>
```

However, this span tag doesn't exist in the DOM, when page loads. It is only added, once the user click on the chat bar.

Any ideas, how do I go about selecting this tag?

Comment: Do you have flexibility to add an `id` attribute to the span tag. Without that you'll have to navigate through the DOM structure to get to it.

Comment: Always start by googling for existing solutions. There are lots of examples you can find with these terms: [detect dom element added](https://www.google.com/#q=detect+dom+element+added), many of those are from stackoverflow. Try to use/adapt some of those, then and only then, in case of problems, add the code to the question and specify what is the specific problem.

Comment: For example, [MutationObserver](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32355787/3959875) or [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891).